# Using the ouput of the 7th column of a log file to gunzip file to a backup directory

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a log file that prints if a batch file processed successfully or not. The 3rd column shows the status letter of "F" for Failed or "C" for complete. The 5th column shows the full path and batch file name.

Example of batch file output

```
392  02/04/2018:2:00  c  4444 /batchprocessing/abc.dat
444  02/04/2018:3:00  F  4442 /batchprocessing/mnop.dat  
3333 02/04/2018:4:00  c  2234 /batchprocessing/xyz.dat
```

I am trying to gunzip all files from column 5 which has a status of "F" in column 3 in a log file called batch_status.log

Here is what i'm thinking:

```
cat batch_status.log | awk '{if ($3 == "F") gunzip -c name_of_file_from_5th_column.dat > /backup/batchfilebackups; else print "No Error";}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a while loop in the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 ; do
    if [ "${f3}" = "F" ] ; then
        gunzip -c "${f5}" >> /backup/batchfilebackups
    else
        # Whatever that means ...
        echo "No Error!"
    fi
done < batch_status.log
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution is perfect fro what i was trying to accomplish

Comment: Glad to see that it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a problem here, `gunzip` is for extracting not for compressing, in that case you should use `gzip`... You don't specify, althoug I think you want to compress the files... use the following command for that:

`for i in $(cat batch_status.log | awk '{if ($3 == "F") print $5}'); do cat $i >> backup; done; gzip backup`